# Where should I put my join() in this multithreaded program?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, parallel-processing, fork-join

I have a program that applies median filtering to elements in an array. I'm using divide-and-conquer with Java's Fork/Join Framework to accomplish this. Here's my `compute()` override:

```
public FilterObject(int lo, int hi, boolean filterType)
{
    this.lo = lo;
    this.hi = hi;
    this.filterType = filterType;
}

public void compute()
{
    if (hi - lo <= SEQUENTIAL_THRESHOLD)
    {
        seqFilter();
    }
    else
    {   
        FilterObject left = new FilterObject(lo, (hi + lo) / 2, filterType);
        FilterObject right = new FilterObject((hi + lo) / 2, hi, filterType);
        left.fork();
        right.compute();
        left.join();
    }
}
```

`seqFilter()` is a static method that does the actual filtering once a subarray is "small enough".

Is my `join()` in the right place? I have a timer running in my `Main` class and the recorded times I'm getting seem way too fast. I'm calling `pool.invoke(filt)`from my `Main` class where `filt` is my `FilterObject` object and `pool` is my `ForkJoinPool`. My timer stops immediately after this call. Is it possible that the main logic is continuing on before the parallel processes have completed? If it is, where can I put `join()` to stop this happening?

EDIT: Additional question - do I even need the join() in this case? The program forks, but it's not like I actually 'join' my forked objects together again because the recursive split index references just get and set from the same arrays.

Comment: It seems fine.  You may want to put debugging statements after the join to ensure it is in fact finishing later.

Comment: I do usually use tracing to debug my programs, but I'm not entirely sure where and how I would place the print statements to ensure this condition.

Comment: What you could do is put a 5 second sleep in the `fork` compute and and a debug after join.  It should print after 5 seconds.